# Vega-lite: Why does graph width affect how the axis labels are formatted?

Tags: vega-lite

When rendering a graph where the X-axis is based on a timestamp which is represented as seconds since the Unix Epoch, I'm observing weird behavior in the generated labels *for specific graph widths*. I've experimented with the vega-lite online editor with a stripped down version of my dataset and only essential configuration options. When width is specified between 521-594, then the timestamp labels render as just time (repeating 6AM, 6PM) for a span of days:

[image: Chart with only time]

These labels are unacceptably vague. At other widths, the generated labels are what I expect:

[image: Chart with day and time]

See [this vega-lite editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-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-LrW2ptIYz2Hp1g8mS0P6gVDVWJwGHlrZ1b6pG6lnO6qa1PpMUi42U1ucIVTsuTb2XQ2N4PCS2lW-Jw-PJXQZE8xlkKYyT3B0DymfNj2bG0ESRaD-TzKZMwQp8vXbX1UOvXs8imJM3TnI4TjOfCV0Te9vzIlsKJQy8c2olov1IsDYTbStmO7d9ikwrDfyQzoePHGDqSeLohM9EQDSXKj3yeRp1w4xCREmJoAIDaQGhI0DEMmTplV4-dJLaVsZIVSNCgvcS0LWaQ2maKy0xfOttMk4oXVc3Ivh+TzHN0kDQ2w8ZGMC1ppGkIjfJbSNo0UwDpEKJy4thEcZkitjsVotSwoKEpsqxPJ2IMsKIKg0yJMc0qQqbMKbLsrszMc-t0o0ooxxamqopU1TyuEkQmuK3t9NCobKtGhMOu47KXUXDrjlOJj7IIwo6ngh9NyGiMozEnqHNaDaWnqx8hu9PDqqOlpaVsjrbVWw71uncaGqG4lSXmu88sG2STkaJ6rx7VLUvS4VmuB99ClpM6dv+9sgZY6GZQ6z6qrWkHFwGibZMKg6ocAwo8gjJbhW6wmA2JvJftx8MEoJ5GieaMq6bTS75tJOGfzxopGb4omWmAtGSQx56e2xYocfehHAeyyDunB74TMx99IM2baeYVTSKaZgNiMeEXd2ugi4LBB7vn51rWjg7EOo5pL9ac6Xzv+hn5buMnR3lmHaZlhU5sd6kRW1TX6Nhdyxcp4OMO58PhqKSG9eDvIfLDzjOq0oO1hmc8lZFeXGkTJbEflti-ddhVI+y4C6lZ-200Dk2e2A-t0-U5bKOb98SdBduwr2xLu8Ao8XfhhUHeHgMtSPfuhsemuHgr8e03Rmunnryvh1L7PWlK4W589CGa5KOOM4BpGBennkx611fRZrkOOvxmutWXu+jnJ1+2KW93d6FlSZ91KT1ViPXkFs7T-0RIAw++oH7-yLLDWB285YIOOO-cOx80EuWQfEIyKtxbvkTGnOiGcRoILrEAsK8JRLZQrLFXBnxvi6yvtSFmb0t7kRWnQl0GDz4RQQcTTeK9chN1AQGFSfdSHqRoVbXqCZhZGwUlPNhRFb7xx1nQisHCRErBZJfa2CZAZ8PUpohBmZhEfzGPJbKp0trSOochWxnRTr21wrYho6jz5-xUWsdYOirEZS-v-doRdZpRlsd5Sx8dq4hLSh1chvjWjlyoUNMxSSWi3SxPnJOrC-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-3hjtU+p4htt2WvmcFA9bzxW6XWTGsYpzUMdGA+BAFcKnLHJwxlR9lbbwyiWfgkjTlX3ay6vR1xrbjaYZhmW75mH1Y1pIzMCDRwd0+oLKVe9w54NUfqYxyDtTUNhItrQ4ZUUy0HPmT5QjFHMXqc6JS2D1o+1Po2neFVcLYYyaJIGszmouPnvU6uPjwySiYWQ0PcVqViJFpYQm4ytJxOiKXUZnkFmxhiqM9WqVtkzNHg6uGytd7NOGfi86QTf4u3udJP5ojkEzMJhC1xQLlbsQkP05-b2wzIINNc3Ig1a46jRtK0wk1FXMSpdhHh8VZssuwlnfMuCubyOKnS0+l9X7jJwo+WWodqrd1rlsppuSVmKtwTa3COznWMLdZEIeorRF8vhW4RVisU312zZmKxwbzqzu3QW2FytwFp0bMSeK1uW24uzZJqu8jdHhlai3YN57T635lrux9x4C3-LedRbp3Sq3O6pvRC6feW34dwtTtUjZkO0cK0bb90pqm21A-rQt6baOixtZ+-MmmMG-rWWlb93s+3evivauEmraafhrim5J2b9S6Tjp5yJ+pZHGs4Tkyz1kW3ZFwu0ft7V8yKwXdF5smbQuUqDv0TLjaiXlZa+Lk9+nCvFxS8tjL3uNSoe1Z9G3QbqPhlFxxbTiTh2FenQh1B+3QtVvcafXYrbanxVc326T4ZpI-1O9jQXUP9wpv-mjy5wbAffdS1Wx133TkUenZE2xTVtvhM+Zuyd8r8zMz-eV2nytmYYGDdB9n1Oq3AeV-qW95joeHdK3G6H26ZbG+7oaVVwb0vekNIaxHph4uj0TDrnDwXCaJhuq89s+fA3ldXZ9RMQ25TQPD4LIsgHhvaXYurRs976-jINqWUOhHkoNrGRbd93XO+RT7d72f+ttmlOTImGaRzX+fhjrzxQ0PxcUe0ALc0nxcTCUxw9y-wmC+2Vx9xdWOFJkzW9Tn3QVj2GyQIjGyVo2-VgKnVM2H15X9yW1gOin20QL7waAH2Vx22oOJim3z1RWOFtkX2IIezZyX3qxpzZhAw8mIIrBfwP0nzqFcVi1b1gMEkv012Hy6H51tzjy-y6BFzH1hHl0Pwsho0Gwrz7w6FDkG3oPXw6CVzUPLSAMn3uBKzMMyktzTRwLzjzXZ0RxwP1xr232UNSi21fznw2DrgkKzmUM2FhTkLqk7WvzJQjCLAW2Z0sJ9FWzX18N7Ez2L0P3gmD2YINU2l0yL2LS-zrHsXLz5iXzrAT2V1iKQN2QbxEMqOnG60pzSIEnywaMn3Bx7xqL728jLzMKH3yKaHdwn0qOlBnxdzSJJhR1nxYOKBpn2yx2HzvGsL4LGF6LSK5iURKKFhJyUMPw3gp3wJ2ImBR0oz710hXzMIqJOJnCcKX2FVyLsJcNvGP1t0mKyOigv0MJgJ2NaBN0gS-xSkWlbRvUnyxEKJsO2OBNjhCL+NTh107z+MTGqKi2H0LCgMH1N2RKyQtyX1dW51GMn14VxK7kPw2lwI+MGL71pFJg2SoPX1pDKUBLQJYJKAx0UO02JLQzwKjy-1SnDyWLDUkOJJKAWw0PxOxG93W1FN4Ibj8gw3xPrQyIsKQNRkaTxKVMAS4OHx5AUIQPRO5MyVWxFKQOKyOLZMnwKWaMfy-0glML5ITiRKtNZDLQuPXzgkcJ0OKOHzgjcOV1sKXxfRR0yPsOlH8OgOaytNRhOQ9KtMWhnWI09OAgWx8JYNKT0zUJaKNIrBb0CMP1jjlzIJzKFg-2cJv3q1EnQzDMP2AjKJsMDJcN+Thyzznz+y20SJYK1Fz2V1rybKlnaPtMrPiRPwFMnzE00yvyX1TiQUG1PybMglIPY2HJmEoIlKQN-UWOlKa1rWHPqSYMVL7xplH1tN9OH0RDSkjKKmH37C22dLnyLDONtKTKyOkzG1VxvOknSmRSX0TCeOV2nJYIrHeOV0NL70Vx+IiJZVbCxFmNlKQOdFBMPNrJLOdBtPXKCVSMnxUgAKKPPK-3iNWy7L-Jpm8I6PXyLngLTMtMP0Bm6L5I-IvPRU5PjRYNOlJOVwfPsNJCpLRM-0PzDy2zmK-3aBZJ9JePYsoV-l3PX0IjuKXzYh7LPOLMiO71W2vKYtsiIr7Mn0zCQwfzhJ4sUUHOzM0t1TYyDU0q-MUwUvAoTFUNtKMLn0yW0J9IQrJWkgMOEtVN3WkmQs4XH3uJvwdTXJ8pEksseXkLdMAvzKPXkO9LBNNJdS6EeHqP2KioLBDJ0pfNRS6BhUi0YoNS6ELWpN1NpS6GxAGL8pcrXFTPgokoTS6HrQmI8p9QXygvJKap+F5JQrW24pSp7VQO2RUOrMPPBPisJT2K5OKuOGVXHWOKauOA7LMKTxGtLXkv6s2mos6qPMmQsjvBJ2cpZQshSlWzssypoK210NmuBFjJy16QskmzwN0qivqwPJQrHJuogrhxmtqrEM5wZNWqqWfijOKqyukpupDR3PAPituvdwrKio6AAp6OXM8pMKvLjK2vuABMUKwKRtuPuoyrysxEGpepJH6tZEwrMN-PxuIgNMishpmFApJvR1-yBqNWqxJrNXEohqRpyiZqivzE4p1N+OKvzHpMT0J3irrCErBKxqaunFoPIoevFs1AWwprTXuAeETOItqsNnFO6vFqxD4s+N5uZJVKJN5rtg5pCpSylm-LMOOryumO1IRsFt5sRGpqBPFudBNLxtVoEjcvIvGt5oHQ729sR21DJvvM1syt0nCrMPwryt0hitssNvioYwatNpTolotv6tvBtx9MbKjpPQBuwuKvVxiNRpLuJkRNytVpBKSoVs8pil3wMvKv2pig6qCrtOrtDsLDkvcIEK2sLEJo7v4pLtLxNrAtCtdQDJqsypdHmqTphviu11s2dqXoIz6pur8y2OltqpKEnNFyS08tSkdXSv6q8OEI0qXs4wsrPt42gNat3tKRJxEtDqERGPTqPqLANoftnp9CXN1qPp-nWJurti2Lis8tKtHNkK2sgnhqGvAaautLnNMviuIgxoFonpSzgjgs6rttVrgiHt0Qyj2tCsXHDo2vzryuGISMKwgaaC2zjvwelAvq7v8tKXWo7pVtDtKWr1F1epgeaDAZDrYdJHFNXs8uAkloXs3PipJjluqs5qapJmeo7rty2q1F7tX1oaUfzB1strpKlmQf6tKm0p-KHNkb6QYuMfm3COMbQY3vUYwlT0BqitXJSLyOKtBQVMUdqppm8qIfGEodVsRHIY7vOtqqLBjttJUryq-qrv6ukzruEZcsTDSoPuSvipoljwQYibaIN0vs8pcluw8OKuaCqs6vCcytgoNsXsKexGDxfv8pUnboCbUdKeJyxJup9EIcCS6v0echUmpvnMydCSIK2sBnnpQsPqardzLS4f8tEY1oKZmdbAWxWKippCOuTs8t7BPvco-pmbvG8f6bYkCoCbwdDtuiic6ppNqtuhUYCcWp2cXA+p3sysLKSoDviqFjvI2uGp2ZcmAa2oHTWcRpmczGhpkd3XgjgY2pIdgvhXcZbseT5vQbMNbINV0ZwY7sYcR10Z6fjjYrxdElCYCfmbJTZVAL4eJt6TZVRPSfrp9VHTIojuWYTXzE8xvtpbXF4dtu2aZZh2fsavZZ+H5prJnsxfapqahYFbYiXPEaZanwJ3duhe-23swZKGOE0f9tYYpdJlW3JZZSnSlI7qJZvwKNMYRoAcVdBE6cmQlptsPMab1dpF2olbTTrC1J5pdTrGlDOpcZ9fqz9uifLqPTrB-2mrecxdbFJcCXTNVaDDGdpVKMTs6qAqZayvptpYsjSb5dqYzcsizuzcxCFYOfZZjwWwxY9fuHKZxZKbDcxBMxMu2RXSbqnPMehdZBacCX4eTY2G1b5PjYzYwiWd1aNaVrwvrZ9ecimp2AAF05gAAzbgXQDAa0MIAYSAQgdAXQWAZAeIDdvEYeSAVgPAeALAAAcgAFJYAL3IA3QegdhH2IAQxIBXAfBEB4ghSXhIAUBGBqB8B4h4w2R-AMBdAABrA9nYeYAAT2sHiEgAkCUH3Y0FffsHgG4E0EYCUGoCg5SEgAsAPcgEXcYGQDEE0AQ8xnODg-3dMDwDQEIBXeiDUCgAQGiFo-xDwBo4Q9PfgEgB6AfEgBg6I5I7I4o9MFLGo-g9MAAEdWB0AHBmAghGAqB+PUOQBH2gA) and modify the width to see how going outside the range of 521-594 affects the labels on the X-axis.

One thing about use of `"scale": {"type": "utc"}` in this configuration: removing this *does* resolve the labeling issue, but then the time shown is not what I want. It is displayed in local time rather than UTC.

I've come up with some workarounds: change the width of the graph or specify a static label format. The latter introduces it's own problems depending on the specified format, since the same label can be used, confusingly, multiple times, e.g. `Mon Mar 23, Mon Mar 23` for different times of that day.

I attempted to find different ways to "fix" the labels via conditional formatting. However, based on examples in the documentation, expressions for creating a format seem limited to static conditions like "is this the first month of the year?" and not relational ones like, "is the day for this label the same as the previous label?" If it's possible to generate more dynamic axis labels via formatting, I'm open to that advice. However, vega-lite *generally* does a good job of generating the labels without further configuration, so understanding why that isn't working for this type of data *at specific widths* is more what I'm after.

So, is my configuration missing something? Do I have any other options other than the workarounds I've mentioned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The label positions and formats are determined automatically based on the content of the chart and the space available (so that labels do not overlap). If the automatic results are not what you want, you can more closely control the tick positions and labels using appropriate axis [label](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/axis.html#labels) and [tick](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/axis.html#ticks) properties.

For example, here we use [d3 time formats](https://github.com/d3/d3-time-format#locale_format) to precisely specify the format of the date labels:

```
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "field": "timestamp",
      "type": "temporal",
      "scale": {"type": "utc"},
      "axis": {"format": "%b %e, %I%p"}
    },
    "y": {"field": "amount", "type": "quantitative"}
  }
```

[image]

Full chart spec in the [editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-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-LrW2ptIYz2Hp1g8mS0P6gVDVWJwGHlrZ1b6pG6lnO6qa1PpMUi42U1ucIVTsuTb2XQ2N4PCS2lW-Jw-PJXQZE8xlkKYyT3B0DymfNj2bG0ESRaD-TzKZMwQp8vXbX1UOvXs8imJM3TnI4TjOfCV0Te9vzIlsKJQy8c2olov1IsDYTbStmO7d9ikwrDfyQzoePHGDqSeLohM9EQDSXKj3yeRp1w4xCREmJoAIDaQGhI0DEMmTplV4-dJLaVsZIVSNCgvcS0LWaQ2maKy0xfOttMk4oXVc3Ivh+TzHN0kDQ2w8ZGMC1ppGkIjfJbSNo0UwDpEKJy4thEcZkitjsVotSwoKEpsqxPJ2IMsKIKg0yJMc0qQqbMKbLsrszMc-t0o0ooxxamqopU1TyuEkQmuK3t9NCobKtGhMOu47KXUXDrjlOJj7IIwo6ngh9NyGiMozEnqHNaDaWnqx8hu9PDqqOlpaVsjrbVWw71uncaGqG4lSXmu88sG2STkaJ6rx7VLUvS4VmuB99ClpM6dv+9sgZY6GZQ6z6qrWkHFwGibZMKg6ocAwo8gjJbhW6wmA2JvJftx8MEoJ5GieaMq6bTS75tJOGfzxopGb4omWmAtGSQx56e2xYocfehHAeyyDunB74TMx99IM2baeYVTSKaZgNiMeEXd2ugi4LBB7vn51rWjg7EOo5pL9ac6Xzv+hn5buMnR3lmHaZlhU5sd6kRW1TX6Nhdyxcp4OMO58PhqKSG9eDvIfLDzjOq0oO1hmc8lZFeXGkTJbEflti-ddhVI+y4C6lZ-200Dk2e2A-t0-U5bKOb98SdBduwr2xLu8Ao8XfhhUHeHgMtSPfuhsemuHgr8e03Rmunnryvh1L7PWlK4W589CGa5KOOM4BpGBennkx611fRZrkOOvxmutWXu+jnJ1+2KW93d6FlSZ91KT1ViPXkFs7T-0RIAw++oH7-yLLDWB285YIOOO-cOx80EuWQfEIyKtxbvkTGnOiGcRoILrEAsK8JRLZQrLFXBnxvi6yvtSFmb0t7kRWnQl0GDz4RQQcTTeK9chN1AQGFSfdSHqRoVbXqCZhZGwUlPNhRFb7xx1nQisHCRErBZJfa2CZAZ8PUpohBmZhEfzGPJbKp0trSOochWxnRTr21wrYho6jz5-xUWsdYOirEZS-v-doRdZpRlsd5Sx8dq4hLSh1chvjWjlyoUNMxSSWi3SxPnJOrC-GQQCfHC+tipg0w6rEjJQtopuICiExoEwloCMqT6VJbt9q2N7F44B7js4+TBIUjOC9enmw1g4j68DfE+U2tE8+O9Jn9PNowsAWD5ndDtksxUrJAo+WnF0sKa9hmiV5Bsl+hyUomIHsE1ZtIZkdx8eIpoPkeStInj01Z0oXlpiGaskmezJrTCjsnZ0YIaYDI7nMh5wKfiFhydssEpJbnYROAYmqPkZoly2cMiYUj8rjK+liiYfzZJiMIY6F0xxZ5jP+lcyF5L7gXN2vc0lqxyX5kRbtGlzLHmdE2gfKlAcIlYtvJ83IFTaU8ptgkxOcLPFgrCuk8V55nIYoIdHYF54f4bJsVi2KECUUOXJcXNxPoZVFyJfTdpWLbpyt2k08VXRLIbJJWql0XQcH8rclGQFeTXUNBFdYlkyj7UWX9bCBVXLgUdAYR6vB0xcmtVdY8G1st9U1ldcpEW+L5mYjqk6wV2awZeyysMukobxhMpdWskUxqrr2ryNOPVcLNQzS1RM+1kiS6oOzb2UNKz7WZNDSceMcL8z3Q2cU4ZdYOgdSmpO1sDLiX5vFdOMG47OWVoeNJcdFagUuiXmWkBEa93RXNV8pxk6NrJrgVm5dxMF3hghUe0Si52VHzjSOkmvb32TryHy3FKaR0VlPaKr1I7TpXvZswsDoz-3hjtU+p4htt2WvmcFA9bzxW6XWTGsYpzUMdGA+BAFcKnLHJwxlR9lbbwyiWfgkjTlX3ay6vR1xrbjaYZhmW75mH1Y1pIzMCDRwd0+oLKVe9w54NUfqYxyDtTUNhItrQ4ZUUy0HPmT5QjFHMXqc6JS2D1o+1Po2neFVcLYYyaJIGszmouPnvU6uPjwySiYWQ0PcVqViJFpYQm4ytJxOiKXUZnkFmxhiqM9WqVtkzNHg6uGytd7NOGfi86QTf4u3udJP5ojkEzMJhC1xQLlbsQkP05-b2wzIINNc3Ig1a46jRtK0wk1FXMSpdhHh8VZssuwlnfMuCubyOKnS0+l9X7jJwo+WWodqrd1rlsppuSVmKtwTa3COznWMLdZEIeorRF8vhW4RVisU312zZmKxwbzqzu3QW2FytwFp0bMSeK1uW24uzZJqu8jdHhlai3YN57T635lrux9x4C3-LedRbp3Sq3O6pvRC6feW34dwtTtUjZkO0cK0bb90pqm21A-rQt6baOixtZ+-MmmMG-rWWlb93s+3evivauEmraafhrim5J2b9S6Tjp5yJ+pZHGs4Tkyz1kW3ZFwu0ft7V8yKwXdF5smbQuUqDv0TLjaiXlZa+Lk9+nCvFxS8tjL3uNSoe1Z9G3QbqPhlFxxbTiTh2FenQh1B+3QtVvcafXYrbanxVc326T4ZpI-1O9jQXUP9wpv-mjy5wbAffdS1Wx133TkUenZE2xTVtvhM+Zuyd8r8zMz-eV2nytmYYGDdB9n1Oq3AeV-qW95joeHdK3G6H26ZbG+7oaVVwb0vekNIaxHph4uj0TDrnDwXCaJhuq89s+fA3ldXZ9RMQ25TQPD4LIsgHhvaXYurRs976-jINqWUOhHkoNrGRbd93XO+RT7d72f+ttmlOTImGaRzX+fhjrzxQ0PxcUe0ALc0nxcTCUxw9y-wmC+2Vx9xdWOFJkzW9Tn3QVj2GyQIjGyVo2-VgKnVM2H15X9yW1gOin20QL7waAH2Vx22oOJim3z1RWOFtkX2IIezZyX3qxpzZhAw8mIIrBfwP0nzqFcVi1b1gMEkv012Hy6H51tzjy-y6BFzH1hHl0Pwsho0Gwrz7w6FDkG3oPXw6CVzUPLSAMn3uBKzMMyktzTRwLzjzXZ0RxwP1xr232UNSi21fznw2DrgkKzmUM2FhTkLqk7WvzJQjCLAW2Z0sJ9FWzX18N7Ez2L0P3gmD2YINU2l0yL2LS-zrHsXLz5iXzrAT2V1iKQN2QbxEMqOnG60pzSIEnywaMn3Bx7xqL728jLzMKH3yKaHdwn0qOlBnxdzSJJhR1nxYOKBpn2yx2HzvGsL4LGF6LSK5iURKKFhJyUMPw3gp3wJ2ImBR0oz710hXzMIqJOJnCcKX2FVyLsJcNvGP1t0mKyOigv0MJgJ2NaBN0gS-xSkWlbRvUnyxEKJsO2OBNjhCL+NTh107z+MTGqKi2H0LCgMH1N2RKyQtyX1dW51GMn14VxK7kPw2lwI+MGL71pFJg2SoPX1pDKUBLQJYJKAx0UO02JLQzwKjy-1SnDyWLDUkOJJKAWw0PxOxG93W1FN4Ibj8gw3xPrQyIsKQNRkaTxKVMAS4OHx5AUIQPRO5MyVWxFKQOKyOLZMnwKWaMfy-0glML5ITiRKtNZDLQuPXzgkcJ0OKOHzgjcOV1sKXxfRR0yPsOlH8OgOaytNRhOQ9KtMWhnWI09OAgWx8JYNKT0zUJaKNIrBb0CMP1jjlzIJzKFg-2cJv3q1EnQzDMP2AjKJsMDJcN+Thyzznz+y20SJYK1Fz2V1rybKlnaPtMrPiRPwFMnzE00yvyX1TiQUG1PybMglIPY2HJmEoIlKQN-UWOlKa1rWHPqSYMVL7xplH1tN9OH0RDSkjKKmH37C22dLnyLDONtKTKyOkzG1VxvOknSmRSX0TCeOV2nJYIrHeOV0NL70Vx+IiJZVbCxFmNlKQOdFBMPNrJLOdBtPXKCVSMnxUgAKKPPK-3iNWy7L-Jpm8I6PXyLngLTMtMP0Bm6L5I-IvPRU5PjRYNOlJOVwfPsNJCpLRM-0PzDy2zmK-3aBZJ9JePYsoV-l3PX0IjuKXzYh7LPOLMiO71W2vKYtsiIr7Mn0zCQwfzhJ4sUUHOzM0t1TYyDU0q-MUwUvAoTFUNtKMLn0yW0J9IQrJWkgMOEtVN3WkmQs4XH3uJvwdTXJ8pEksseXkLdMAvzKPXkO9LBNNJdS6EeHqP2KioLBDJ0pfNRS6BhUi0YoNS6ELWpN1NpS6GxAGL8pcrXFTPgokoTS6HrQmI8p9QXygvJKap+F5JQrW24pSp7VQO2RUOrMPPBPisJT2K5OKuOGVXHWOKauOA7LMKTxGtLXkv6s2mos6qPMmQsjvBJ2cpZQshSlWzssypoK210NmuBFjJy16QskmzwN0qivqwPJQrHJuogrhxmtqrEM5wZNWqqWfijOKqyukpupDR3PAPituvdwrKio6AAp6OXM8pMKvLjK2vuABMUKwKRtuPuoyrysxEGpepJH6tZEwrMN-PxuIgNMishpmFApJvR1-yBqNWqxJrNXEohqRpyiZqivzE4p1N+OKvzHpMT0J3irrCErBKxqaunFoPIoevFs1AWwprTXuAeETOItqsNnFO6vFqxD4s+N5uZJVKJN5rtg5pCpSylm-LMOOryumO1IRsFt5sRGpqBPFudBNLxtVoEjcvIvGt5oHQ729sR21DJvvM1syt0nCrMPwryt0hitssNvioYwatNpTolotv6tvBtx9MbKjpPQBuwuKvVxiNRpLuJkRNytVpBKSoVs8pil3wMvKv2pig6qCrtOrtDsLDkvcIEK2sLEJo7v4pLtLxNrAtCtdQDJqsypdHmqTphviu11s2dqXoIz6pur8y2OltqpKEnNFyS08tSkdXSv6q8OEI0qXs4wsrPt42gNat3tKRJxEtDqERGPTqPqLANoftnp9CXN1qPp-nWJurti2Lis8tKtHNkK2sgnhqGvAaautLnNMviuIgxoFonpSzgjgs6rttVrgiHt0Qyj2tCsXHDo2vzryuGISMKwgaaC2zjvwelAvq7v8tKXWo7pVtDtKWr1F1epgeaDAZDrYdJHFNXs8uAkloXs3PipJjluqs5qapJmeo7rty2q1F7tX1oaUfzB1strpKlmQf6tKm0p-KHNkb6QYuMfm3COMbQY3vUYwlT0BqitXJSLyOKtBQVMUdqppm8qIfGEodVsRHIY7vOtqqLBjttJUryq-qrv6ukzruEZcsTDSoPuSvipoljwQYibaIN0vs8pcluw8OKuaCqs6vCcytgoNsXsKexGDxfv8pUnboCbUdKeJyxJup9EIcCS6v0echUmpvnMydCSIK2sBnnpQsPqardzLS4f8tEY1oKZmdbAWxWKippCOuTs8t7BPvco-pmbvG8f6bYkCoCbwdDtuiic6ppNqtuhUYCcWp2cXA+p3sysLKSoDviqFjvI2uGp2ZcmAa2oHTWcRpmczGhpkd3XgjgY2pIdgvhXcZbseT5vQbMNbINV0ZwY7sYcR10Z6fjjYrxdElCYCfmbJTZVAL4eJt6TZVRPSfrp9VHTIojuWYTXzE8xvtpbXF4dtu2aZZh2fsavZZ+H5prJnsxfapqahYFbYiXPEaZanwJ3duhe-23swZKGOE0f9tYYpdJlW3JZZSnSlI7qJZvwKNMYRoAcVdBE6cmQlptsPMab1dpF2olbTTrC1J5pdTrGlDOpcZ9fqz9uifLqPTrB-2mrecxdbFJcCXTNVaDDGdpVKMTs6qAqZayvptpYsjSb5dqYzcsizuzcxCFYOfZZjwWwxY9fuHKZxZKbDcxBMxMu2RXSbqnPMehdZBacCX4eTY2G1b5PjYzYwiWd1aNaVrwvrZ9ecimp2AAF1kxIAAAzbgXQDAa0NIQgdAXQWAZAeINIUBSAVgPAeALAAAcgAFJYAz3IAegegNAQxIBXAfBEB4ghSXhIAUBGBqB8B4h4w2R-AMBdAABrfd+YAAT2sHiEgAkCUD3cffsHgG4E0EYCUGoH3Z2EgAsAw7xGXcYGQDEE0Gg8xm-Ag6g9MDwDQEIFXeiD8Fw4QGiD3dCDI6Y6gGPfgFvdI-QAsEYFgDA5XbXaCGg4vfYDAAveQDKAvYAEkL3ah72UgHxIBwP+P8PCPoPSxzhIPWPIAABHVgdABwZgIIRgKgW9h9kAHoIAA)

Comment: I mentioned in my question that specifying the label format "fixes" the problem, but I'm not completely satisfied with that as a solution. Granted, your format is better than the one I was using since it alleviates repeated use of the same label. I'm still stumped why the format of labels would be so impacted by the width of the graph, especially if the format is partially determined by the content of the chart. That is, why use "6 AM" instead of "Mar 23" or "Mon"? All are roughly the same length, and the latter two make more sense given the the data represents days and not hours.

Comment: The answer to your question is that the renderer uses a heuristic to choose a reasonable default display for a given span of dates within a certain number of pixels. You've found a situation in which the results of that heuristic do not match your personal preferences... you have two options: (1) specify formats explicitly, as in my answer, or (2) contribute a patch to the vega project that improves the heuristic it uses.

Comment: Can you provide any more specifics for where I can find that heuristic in the vega project? I'd love to better understand how it works and contribute, if I can.